# What type of Logical Fallacy is this?

Tags: fallacies

I've been doing a lot of research lately.  A few weeks ago I stumbled across logical fallacies and it opened my eyes to the things I've always known were BS, but I couldn't quite put my finger on.  I can now.  The problem is that there are soooo many different types of fallacies, that I find myself spending too much time trying to find the specific logical fallacy to define my particular question. For instance:  What is it called when a description of something is changed to something else to cover up a "big lie."  The thing is, nobody seems to have realized that the nomenclature was changed.  This might be due to the fact that that it in most cases, it has been described by the acronym (CCD) so when the deception occurred, nobody was the wiser. Here is an example:

"**Consumer** Complaint Database" ("CCD") was changed to "**Credit** Complaint Database" ("CCD")

This was not a mistake, it was done on purpose, but I don't know what it's called and it's driving me crazy! It's some type of "shift" I think, but I can't find the exact term.

Comment: That doesn't look like a logical fallacy to me. It's more like a deliberate misrepresentation.

Comment: Thank you, Sir.  Could it be considered a bait-and-switch?

Comment: This database is a set of complaints made to the Consumer Financial Protection Bureau.  Consumers may have gotten the idea that the agency deals with all types of consumer complaints, whereas it only deals with financial matters.  Thus, the name change reflects more accurately the kinds of complaints with which the agency deals.

Comment: Thank you Xanne, but what I posted was an example, not the actual term.  unfortunately, I can't list the exact object at this time, but thank you.  I really appreciate your input.

Comment: Some examples: (A) In India, we have highly reputed "**D**elhi **P**ublic **S**chool" which is usually known by acronym **DPS**. Another school wanted to use that reputation by calling itself "**DPS** Public School" (B) While selling housing sites, the real estate seller will say he has government approval and will give the "**A**pproval **N**umber" AN/2017/123 for gullible buyers; when careful buyers check the "**A**pproval **N**umber", it will turn out that **AN** is not "**A**pproval **N**umber", it is "*A**pplication **N**umber".  [[ It is not logical fallacy; it is misleading or fraud ]]

Comment: I can't see how changing a description to cover up a "big lie" is a logical fallacy. Fallacies can generally be interpreted as unintentional (even if it isn't; the point is any logical fallacy **could** be a simple mistake in logic). There's no way a deliberate deception could be (a) be a mistake in logic (b) accidental. If you really mean a logical fallacy then your description will need to be better, I'm afraid.

Comment: I can't think of anything beyond saying it's a **euphemistic** use of words. However, it has made me want to revisit Orwell's _1984_ and G.K. Chesterton's essay "On Evil Euphemisms".

Comment: There is a fair amount of discussion about whether **obfuscation** is a fallacy. I tend to think not, but it's certainly a relevant concept here.

Comment: Perhaps the term you were searching for is "semantic shift", but I think that's mostly used as a linguistic term for change in language over time.